# Clear InternetExplorerDriver cookies selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I create my internetExplorer instance, I use the following:

```
public static WebDriver internetExplorerWebWDriver() {
        DesiredCapabilities returnCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        return new InternetExplorerDriver(returnCapabilities);
```

My problem is: I have to open a secondary internetExplorer window with cleared cookie/Cache/Session and authenticate a user during the login.

Right now, using this code, cookie is not deleted because authentication not appears and I cannot login with different user. (seems to me, the first login is saved, and used in the second window)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In your `@BeforeClass` add this `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`

Comment: I tried it as well but no luck so far. I run my tests locally, and it seems, the new instance has all the cookies and the authentication form does not appear..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting IE after calling DeleteAllCookies each time ?

Placing a driver.quit() in the after class if you using junit ?

Comment: Problem here is that I need to open two window simultaneously so if I kill the driver, the first window will be closed and I lost the main session. I need both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented similar problems, try with the code below in @Before method:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("localStorage.clear();");      
js.executeScript("sessionStorage.clear();");
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```